# mplleaflet: Add the plot legend and select initial zoom

Tags: python, matplotlib, leaflet, geopandas

Can anyone guide me on how to add a legend to the mplleaflet html plot. And second how to choose an initial zoom?

*open shapefile in geopandas and plot property on interactive web map*

Example Code:

```
import geopandas as gp
shapefile = 'shapefile/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp'
df_shapefile_countries = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(shapefile)

import mplleaflet
ax = df_shapefile_countries .plot(column='pop_est')
mplleaflet.show(fig=ax.figure)
```

Example Image: 
I would like to immediately zoom for example to South East Asia

[image: World map]

Comment: I think the functionality to add a legend is not ready: https://github.com/jwass/mplleaflet/issues/35

Comment: I see, thanks, do you have a idea for the second question?

Answer (score 3):

I think, right now, the functionality you want is not implemented.

For the first question regarding the legend, have a look here: https://github.com/jwass/mplleaflet/issues/35

For the second question, being creative, you can hack a zoom creating a transparent plot with the coordinates you want. For instance, have a look to the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplleaflet

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Your plot
ax.plot([10, 20, 30], [10, 20, 30])

# A second plot with some coordinates you want to use as the limits
# For instance, I want a plot with  x between (-100, 100)
ax.plot([-100, 100], [10, 30], alpha = 0)

mplleaflet.show(fig = ax.figure)
```

This is far from perfect, only works if you want a further view (I don't know if in english is said like this) but it is better than nothing. 
`ax.set_xlim` and/or `ax.set_ylim` doesn't work so you can't have a zoom closer than what you want to plot in the map.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I supposed that... :-( Sorry, I can't find a solution. Maybe you should use folium.

Comment: Two and a half years later, is there any update on this? It would be very useful to have these features implemented.